# memset on a statically-allocated zlib Byte array in a library crashes an Objective-C++ program

Tags: xcode, zlib, objective-c++, memset

I'm writing a library that uses a statically-allocated C-array of type Byte, defined in zlib.h.  I'm finding that the code crashes on a call to memset.  The complete code looks like this:

```
Byte compressedDataBuffer[kLabelBufSiz]; 
memset (compressedDataBuffer, 0, (kLabelBufSiz * sizeof(Byte)));
```

I tried pre-computing the value of kLabelBufSiz * sizeof(Byte) and using the numeric value for the memset, but it made no difference.  This is a single-threaded program and there is no code between the two calls, so I know that the memory and pointer are not changing.  I confirmed that sizeof(Byte) is 1.  I tried changing the array type to char, and that stopped the crash, so it seems that the Byte type may be playing a role here.

I wrote a smaller program that calls this library function, and that one does not crash.  The non-crashing program is pure C++, whereas the crashing one is Objective-C++.  I'm building them both on Mac OSX 10.6.7, with gcc-4.2 and XCode.  Is there something about ObjC++ that could cause problems here?  I've never had problems with C++ libraries called from ObjC++ before, but that doesn't mean they don't exist. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Byte is a wrapper class.  use char instead of byte.  unless you have to use Byte, in that case, don't use memset

Comment: I do have to use Byte, unfortunately.  Is there a better way to zero out the array than memset?

Comment: you could use a for loop.  memset is really only used for big blocks of memory, where it's faster than a for loop

Comment: That's a good idea!  BTW, I did try putting a Byte in the last place in the array, and it worked (compressedDataBuffer[kLabelBufSiz-1] = (Byte)1;).  I'm not sure why memset causes a problem.

Comment: I tried a for loop, and it fixes the crash.  The loop requires about 130,000 iterations, unfortunately, but at least it works.  I wish I knew why memset was failing.